# Issue with jquery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pass-by-reference

The data passes fine in jQuery but when trying to pass it to PHP it starts bugging out and everything is NULL. I used alert boxes and it seems like the data and values are stored and then I tried using ajax to pass it to a php file I have and then I did var_dump to test the variable and it is NULL.  Can someone please help me?

Please help.

jQuery code:

```
            var dataString = 'Billing_Name=' + Billing_Name + '&Billing_Email=' + Billing_Email + '&Billing_Card=' + Billing_Card + '&Month=' + Month + '&Year=' + Year + '&Billing_StreetAddress1=' + Billing_StreetAddress1 + 'Billing_StreetAddress2=' + Billing_StreetAddress2 + '&Billing_City=' + Billing_City + '&Billing_State=' + Billing_State + '&Billing_Zip=' + Billing_Zip + '&Billing_Phone=' + Billing_Phone;   
     alert(dataString); 

    $.ajax({
        //cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: dataString,
        //  dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",  
    success: function(ret) {
        alert(ret); 
        //alert("it has been sent"); 
        //$.get("https://affordableapparelny.com/ssl/checkoutprocess.php",dataString), 
        alert("it was sent"); 
        window.location.href="http://affordableapparelnewyork.com/ssl/test.php"; 
                },
     error: function(xhr, type, exception){
                          alert("something went wront here"); 
                          alert("Error: " + type);
                          console.log('@Error: '+errorThrown);
                          console.log('@Status: '+status);
                          console.log('@Status Text: '+xhr.statusText);
                            }
    });
```

and here is the PHP code

```
 <?php

   $BName=$_POST['Billing_Name'];
 $BEmail=$_POST['Billing_Email'];
 $BCard=$_POST['Billing_Card'];
 var_dump($BName); 

$errormessages=array();
$errorcount=0;
 if(isset($_POST) && is_array($_POST) && count($_POST)){ 
  foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
   $$key=$value; $$key=trim($$key);
   $$key=strip_tags ($$key); 
   $$key=stripslashes($$key);
   $$key=htmlentities($$key);
   echo "$key $value <br>";
  // echo "is it working"; 
 }
 }
 else { $errormessages[]="Post variable not set"; }
```

Comment: Where do you define the values that go into `dataString` and how do you get those values? That's where the error should be.

Comment: var Billing_Name= $("input#Billing_Name").val();

Comment: php has extra "}" before "else"  ... good online php syntax checker http://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/

Comment: oh the foreach "}"  is inside the if statement so i think it fits and is syntax wiise ok

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are just missing an ampersand `&` here:

```
Billing_StreetAddress1 + 'Billing_StreetAddress2='
```

??

to see your errors on the client side, use the developer console, on the server side, just dump the entire $_POST-variable to see what you received.

and last but not least, check out this way of sending data:

```
var dataObj = {
  'Billing_Name' : $('#Billing_Name').val(), 
  'Billing_Email' : $('#Billing_Email').val() 
};

$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "test.php", data: dataObj, success: ...
```

Comment: than you so much for catching that I fixed it but the variable is still null :-(

Comment: you need to show more code, but reduce it to just enough code to duplicate your problem. show the html-structure and the entire js-function definition (with signatures and usage, but without checking individual parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the data as a JSON as @mindandmedia pointed out, maybe your environment is not set to accept content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`